# FInding key bindings referenced as a text string surrounded by angle brackets

Tags: emacs, key-bindings, notation

Quoting from the help buffer for the function `kill-line`:

> It is bound to <deleteline>.

The question is how to find out exactly what key sequence `<deleteline>` refers to?

Answer (score 2):

The subject of the question is [angle-bracket notation](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/EmacsKeyNotation#toc2) for 'pseudo keys'.

The `describe-bindings` command can be used to find the function that a pseudo key is bound to (if any) by the looks...

> [10.8 Other Help Commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Misc-Help.html) ... C-h b displays a list of all the key bindings now in effect: first the
>   local bindings of the current minor modes, then the local bindings
>   defined by the current major mode, and finally the global bindings

`where-is` can be used to find the key, etc., that a function is bound to:

> [10.2 Documentation for a Key](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Key-Help.html#Key-Help) ... C-h w command RET lists the keys that are bound to command. It displays the list in the echo area. If it
>   says the command is not on any key, that means you must use M-x to run
>   it. C-h w runs the command where-is.